# Angular 12 Lazy Load Component Dynamically code doing nothing

Tags: angular, angular12

I am trying to lazy load a component dynamically with angular 12 but I get no errors and the component does not appear either.

Here is the code:

app.component.ts

```
import {Component,ViewContainerRef,ComponentFactoryResolver } from '@angular/core';

...

constructor(private vcRef: ViewContainerRef, private cResolver: ComponentFactoryResolver) { }
```

and the method:

```
async load() {
    this.vcRef.clear();
    const { MyModalComponent } = await import('../my-modal.component');
    this.vcRef.createComponent(this.cResolver.resolveComponentFactory(MyModalComponent));
  }
```

app.component.html

```
<button (click)="load()">Load it</button>
```

The html in MyModalComponent is just

```
<p>Component Here</p>
```

What I'm I missing or what I'm I doing wrong here?

Comment: What is `this.vcRef` referenced to? Do you have `ng-template` somewhere in your `app.component.html`? Please provide more relevant code to your questions, there are missing info/pieces to figure out what's going on

Comment: How do I assign vcRef to something?

Comment: Your code should work. Try adding lazy component to `entryComponents` . https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-module-sandbox-kmnbbs? But this is not the best way, see the doc: https://angular.io/guide/dynamic-component-loader

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are creating the component dynamically, but that's all. You also need to add the component the the Angular Component tree and the DOM:

```js
async load {
    const { MyModalComponent } = await import('../my-modal.component');
    // 1. Create a component reference
    const componentRef = this.componentFactoryResolver
      .resolveComponentFactory<MyModalComponent>(component)
      .create(this.injector);

    // 2. Attach component to the appRef so that it's inside the ng component tree
    this.appRef.attachView(componentRef.hostView);

    // 3. Get DOM element from the component
    const domElement = (componentRef.hostView as EmbeddedViewRef<any>)
      .rootNodes[0] as HTMLElement;

    // 4. Append DOM element to the body
    document.body.appendChild(domElement);
}
```

Comment: Does this code replace the code in my method or is it added?

Comment: Replace, I improved the clarity

Answer (score 0):

Since Angular 12 componentFactoryResolver is no more needed.

If you have a `ng-template` target in you HTML template :

```
<ng-template #myTemplate></ng-template>
```

Here is what you need in your @Component :

```
@ViewChild('myTemplate', { read: ViewContainerRef })
  myTemplate!: ViewContainerRef;

async #loadComponent() {
    const { MyComponent } = await import('path/to/your/component');
    if (this.myTemplate) {
      this.myTemplate.clear();
      this.myTemplate.createComponent(MyComponent);
    }
  }
```